# When to load a variable used in a footer (over all views)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where in the in the footer we're randomly choosing a nice sentence from a bunch of sentences. So far we had an array of those sentences in the view file and were iterating over it but this makes the `footer.html.erb` pretty unreadable.

I thought of creating a csv or text file in the public folder and then loading the text from there - but where should the code to parse the csv go, in the view? In the application controller?
Or should I create a custom initializer that loads the array of sentences when starting the server and in the view I randomly take one each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to the helper, and just call the helper method in view

In `application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  NICE_SENTENCES = [
    'Nice Sentence One',
    'Nice Sentence Two'
  ]

  def random_sentence
    NICE_SENTENCES.sample
  end
end
```

In view `footer.html.erb`

```
<%= random_sentence %>
```

Hope that helps!